# How to change text color in Angular mat-table when a row is selected?

Tags: angular, mat-table

I would like to change the text color of a selected row in mat-table. The background is changed correctly but not the text with the following code:

```
.highlight {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

in html

```
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns; let i = index;" 
                (click)="selectRow(i + this.paginatorList.pageIndex*this.paginatorClaimList.pageSize + 1, i);"
                [ngClass]="{'highlight': selectedRowList === i}" ></tr>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: You probably need to go deeper like `.highlight { td { color: red } }`